# how to rename the project in gradle instead of using folder name?

Tags: gradle

We would like to have all subprojects be called sdi-xxx and sdi-yyy so when we run gradle eclipse it generates eclipse project names correctly in .project and when we build it creates a jar file with the name sdi-xxxx.jar and sid-yyyy.jar.  I have seen this somewhere but for the life of me, I can't find it in the doc(that doc is huge and I know I saw it there somewhere).

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 22, accepted):

settings.gradle:

```
prefixProjectName(rootProject, "sdi-")

def prefixProjectName(project, prefix) {
  project.name = prefix + project.name
  project.children.each { prefixProjectName(it, prefix) }
}
```

Comment: what if I only want to change to name of one of the children?

Comment: `project(":foo").name = "bar"`

Answer (score 14):

Based on suggestion of Peter N, I currently have the following in my parent settings.gradle

```
include 'xxx', 'yyy'
rootProject.children.each { it.name = "sdi-" + it.name }
```

If you want the name of the root parent used as prefix, you could do

```
include 'xxx', 'yyy'
rootProject.children.each { it.name = rootProject.name + it.name }
```