# Gradle multi-project naming: How can I set a property (e.g. baseName) for all subprojects?

Tags: gradle, multi-project

I started using Gradle for multi-projects. However, the Gradle manual does not give many hints for the best practice regarding the naming of subprojects.

I have the multiproject with the name 'datalogger' that consists of two subprojects 'core' and 'entries':

```
- datalogger
--- core
--- entries
```

When I build the project, I get the jars 'core-1.0.jar' and 'entries-1.0.jar'. How do I manage that the naming is 'datalogger-core-1.0.jar' and 'datalogger-entries-1.0.jar' in a generic way? I know, I could change the name of the folders as follows:

```
- datalogger
--- datalogger-core
--- datalogger-entries
```

But that would not be regarded as good approach, I assume. I could also manually change the `archivesBaseName` of each project. But I would rather find a way to do this in a generic way, as mentioned before.

Comment: [Spring](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework) does it by naming every subproject spring-xxx. [hibernate](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm) does it this way as well.

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks, maybe this is not bad practice as i assumed in the first place. It could actually solve all problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
subprojects {
    tasks.withType(Jar) {
        baseName = "datalogger-$project.name"
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could set `archivesBaseName` in a similar way.

Comment: The maven-publishing task ignores archivesBaseName

Answer (score 1):

We're handling this by renaming the subprojects, new names will be taken into account when creating/naming your jars:
ref: [how to rename the project in gradle instead of using folder name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530420/how-to-rename-the-project-in-gradle-instead-of-using-folder-name/14269538#14269538)

```
include 'xxx', 'yyy'
rootProject.children.each { it.name = rootProject.name + it.name }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin: in the root project's build file:

```
subprojects {
    tasks.withType<Jar> {
        archiveBaseName.set("${rootProject.name}-${project.name}")
    }
}
```