# Gradle multiprojects with same name, different paths

Tags: gradle

I have a monolith Gradle project that contains multiple subprojects, each with its own subprojects, like so:

```
project
  |
  |-- subprojectA
  |    |-- models
  |
  |-- subprojectB
  |    |-- models
```

This compiles fine but the issue is when I try to add a dependency on `:subprojectB:models` to `:subprojectA:models`, Gradle thinks `:subprojectA:models` is trying to add a dependency on itself and complains of a circular dependency, even though I specify the fully qualified path like so (in subprojectA's `build.gradle`):

`compile project(':subprojectB:models')`

How can I avoid this? Can subprojects not have the same name even if their paths are unique?

Comment: Related (with a focus on Eclipse, though): https://stackoverflow.com/q/26407340/1127485

Answer (score 2):

That's currently a [known Gradle issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/847) as Gradle by default uses the parent directory name as the project name. You can work around the issue as described [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/847#issuecomment-450259535) by assigning unique subproject names in the root project's `settings.gradle` like so:

```
include ':subprojectA:models-a', ':subprojectB:models-b'
project(':subprojectA:models-a').projectDir = file('subprojectA/models')
project(':subprojectB:models-b').projectDir = file('subprojectB/models')
```

Answer (score 1):

Project identity for dependency resolution is based on the `group:name:version` or GAV coordinates, as explained in the [linked Gradle issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/847).

So you need to make sure your different `models` project have different GAVs.

- One way to make this happen is to make the `subprojectA` (or `B`) [part of the `group`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/847#issuecomment-287515195).
- Another way is [to assign names](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/847#issuecomment-450259535) that are not based on the containing folder.

Comment: That's only true for Maven, not for Gradle. In fact, the artifacts generated by Gradle subprojects are by default not published to anywhere (like maven would do to the local maven repository), so there *are* no GAV coordinates by default for artifacts created from Gradle subprojects.

Comment: My answer could have given more context and showed the different options for working around it. It was and is however correct. Even without publication, dependency resolution transforms projects into their GAVs for conflict resolution.

Comment: That's an interesting and surprising statement, esp. as a Gradle project's default version (if unset) is literally "unspecified". Do you have any links to docs or Gradle's source code that show that Gradle indeed creates (somewhat artificial) GAV coordinates to resolve conflicts between subprojects in the same root project (not between subprojects and third-party artifacts)?