# Gradle multi-poject build api(project(..)) dependencies stoped working

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

So I got this project in kotlin that consists of multiple sub projects. All of them are link with single `settings.gradle` file. It was all working fine until after a week of coding another part I noticed that i get a lot of compilation errors from one of the modules. So I started digging and found out that Intellij couldn't import classes from another sub project even though it is dependent on it via `api project(':lib:content:model')`. I couldn't figure out the reason why it stopped working and tried to build the project without intellij, just with graddlew. Then i got strange error:

command: `./gradlew :lib:game:model:build`

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:lib:game:model:classes
\--- :lib:game:model:compileJava
     +--- :lib:game:model:compileKotlin
     |    +--- :lib:game:model:jar
     |    |    +--- :lib:game:model:classes (*)
     |    |    +--- :lib:game:model:compileJava (*)
     |    |    +--- :lib:game:model:compileKotlin (*)
     |    |    \--- :lib:game:model:kaptKotlin
     |    |         +--- :lib:game:model:jar (*)
     |    |         \--- :lib:game:model:kaptGenerateStubsKotlin
     |    |              \--- :lib:game:model:jar (*)
     |    \--- :lib:game:model:kaptKotlin (*)
     \--- :lib:game:model:jar (*)

(*) - details omitted (listed previously)
```

I tried to google my way out of it but none of the suggestions from the internet worked for me. The strangest thing is that it USED to work when i was writing it previously. Then i just switched to another module and when i came back it was all like this, broken =(

I tried to isolate bugged code into test and ended up with `lib` module containing two sub modules `content` and `game`. Another one is `project-types` module where I store gradle plugins to overcome configuration duplication. `content` project just have one subproject called `model` and `game` project has three: `api`, `impl`, and also 'model`.

`lib->game->model` project depends on `lib->content->model`
`lib->game->impl` project depends in `lib->game->api`

So another really strange thing is that `lib->game->impl` WORKD just fine and compiles even when he is dependent on `lib->game->api`. But the same thing doesn't work for 'lib->game->model' which uses THE SAME mechanism to depend on 'lib->content->model'

So I'm lost and don't know what to do. There is a good reason I need all of them to be different projects but I don't want to put myself through the hell of publishing new artifact to local repo every time I change code in one of them. Can someone please help me fix it T-T

My `./gradlew -q projects` output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project 'test'
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'test'
\--- Project ':lib'
     +--- Project ':lib:content'
     |    \--- Project ':lib:content:model'
     \--- Project ':lib:game'
          +--- Project ':lib:game:api'
          +--- Project ':lib:game:impl'
          \--- Project ':lib:game:model'

Included builds
\--- Included build ':project-types'
```

`project-types` contains `common` and `kotlin-project` sub projects.

`common` build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy-gradle-plugin'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

and `commons.gradle` file inside src:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.13.4'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.13.4'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.4'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.13.4'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-paranamer:2.13.4'

    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.36'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.11'

    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15'
}
```

`kotlin-project` build.gradle file:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
    }
}

rootProject.name = 'project-types'

include 'commons'
include 'kotlin-project'
```

and it's `kotlin-project.gradle` file inside src:

```
plugins {
    id 'commons'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:1.6.4'

    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin'

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.9.1'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:4.8.1'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:4.0.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.1'

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '17'
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjsr305=strict', '-Xemit-jvm-type-annotations']
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '17'
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjsr305=strict', '-Xemit-jvm-type-annotations']
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

So my main projects structure is:

My `./setting.gradle` file content:

```
rootProject.name = 'test'

includeBuild 'project-types'

include 'lib:game'
include 'lib:game:model'
include 'lib:game:api'
include 'lib:game:impl'

include 'lib:content'
include 'lib:content:model'
```

`./build.gradle` file content

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version "1.7.21" apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt' version "1.7.21" apply false
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

`./lib/content/model/build.gradle` file content:

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-project'
}

group 'cvazer.test'
version '1.0.0'

dependencies {

}
```

`./lib/game/api/build.gradle` file content:

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-project'
}

group 'cvazer.test'
version '1.0.0'

dependencies {

}
```

`./lib/game/impl/build.gradle` file content:

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-project'
}

group 'cvazer.test'
version '1.0.0'

dependencies {
    api project(':lib:game:api')
}
```

`./lib/game/model/build.gradle` file content: (The one with the problem)

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-project'
}

group 'cvazer.test'
version '1.0.0'

dependencies {
    api project(':lib:content:model')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle has issues resolving dependencies when two subproject names are the same, even if the paths are different.

- https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/847
- [Gradle multiprojects with same name, different paths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58602820/4161471)
- https://discuss.gradle.org/t/dependency-substitution-wrong-with-more-than-one-sub-project-with-same-name/7253

You have two subprojects, both called 'model'

- `:lib:game:model`
- `:lib:content:model`

Gradle can't distinguish between them.

I would recommend renaming your subprojects to flatter, without nesting, and making the names of each subproject unique.

```
└── lib/
    ├── game
    ├── game-model
    ├── game-api
    ├── game-impl
    ├── content
    └── content-model
```

Comment: Yeah, it works after renaming. Flattening isn't necessary, but I might prefer it that way now when I'm thinking about it. Although it's a mystery how it used to WORK like a week ago in the same configuration and just suddenly STOPPED working just by itself. The only thing I can think of is my IDE got updated, but I fail to see how it would have affect gradle mechanisms =(