# Gradle circular dependency, but not seeing it

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

So I have a "main" module called `main-data`. It doesn't depend on any of my other projects.

main-data build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:${Versions.postgresVersion}")
    implementation("com.zaxxer:HikariCP:${Versions.hikariVersion}")
}

// To run: ./gradlew flywayMigrate
flyway {
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app"
    user = "app"
    password = "app"
    validateOnMigrate = false
}
```

Then I have another project `vendor-data` that depends on `main-data`.

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":app-main-data"))
}
```

And finally I have another module `invoice-data` that depends on both.

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":app-main-data"))
    implementation(project(":app-modules:vendors:data"))
}
```

And the error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:app-modules:invoices:data:compileJava
+--- :app-modules:invoices:data:compileJava (*)
\--- :app-modules:invoices:data:compileKotlin
     +--- :app-modules:invoices:data:compileJava (*)
     \--- :app-modules:invoices:data:compileKotlin (*)

(*) - details omitted (listed previously)
```

My settings.gradle

```
include(
    ":app-main",
    ":app-main-data",
)


include(
    ":app-modules:vendors:data",
)

include(
    ":app-modules:invoices:api",
    ":app-modules:invoices:data",
)
```

Where is the circular dependency here? As soon as I remove `implementation(project(":app-modules:vendors:data"))` from invoice project it works. But I'm puzzled.

Can anyone understand this?

Comment: Gradle requires subprojects have distinct names, but you have two subprojects named `data`. [Gradle multi-poject build api(project(..)) dependencies stoped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74603267/gradle-multi-poject-build-apiproject-dependencies-stoped-working)