# How to use springboot + gradle + convention + libs.versions.toml + kts to build a multi-module project?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

My module structure:

```
--project
  --build-logic
    --convention
  --feature
    --article
      --database
```

`build-logic/convention/build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

dependencies{
    compileOnly(libs.kotlin.gradle.plugin)
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        register("springboot"){
            id = "sage.springboot"
            implementationClass = "SpringbootConventionPlugin"
        }
    }
}
```

`build-logic/convention/src/main/kotlin/com/sage/server/SpringbootConventionPlugin.kt`

```kotlin
package com.sage.server

import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.VersionCatalogsExtension
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.getByType

class SpringbootConventionPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        with(target) {
            val libs = project.extensions.getByType<VersionCatalogsExtension>().named("libs")
            pluginManager.apply(libs.findPlugin("kotlin-jvm").get().get().pluginId)
            pluginManager.apply(libs.findPlugin("kotlin-spring").get().get().pluginId)
            pluginManager.apply(libs.findPlugin("spring-framework-boot").get().get().pluginId)
            pluginManager.apply(libs.findPlugin("spring-dependency-management").get().get().pluginId)
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error when using a custom plugin:
`feature/article/database/build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("sage.springboot")
}
```

error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.InvalidPluginException: Could not find implementation class 'SpringbootConventionPlugin' for plugin 'sage.springboot' specified in jar:file:/D:/Software/.gradle/caches/jars-9/ceb3f2c77f3429950687bbe83d9848a4/convention.jar!/META-INF/gradle-plugins/sage.springboot.properties.
```

Where am I doing wrong?

I searched for a long time on the Internet, but there is no example using the following technology stack `springboot + gradle + convention + libs.versions.toml + kts`, can you provide some resources or code samples? For those who are new to gradle, it is really difficult to continue without relevant resources.

###### first edit

change `build-logic/convention/src/main/kotlin/com/sage/server/SpringbootConventionPlugin.kt` to `build-logic/convention/src/main/kotlin/SpringbootConventionPlugin.kt`.

fixed `Could not find implementation class 'SpringbootConventionPlugin'`

---

module `core:api`

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("sage.springboot")
}

dependencies {
    api(libs.spring.boot.starter.web)
}
```

module `feature:article:api`

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("sage.springboot")
}

dependencies{
    api(project(":core:api"))
    implementation(project(":feature:article:service"))
}
```

I used `api()` instead of `implementation()`, **but the dependencies were not passed**.

`feature:article:api` has a dependency on `core:api`, and `core:api` has a dependency on `libs.spring.boot.starter.web`. But `feature:article:api` does not have a dependency on `libs.spring.boot.starter.web`.

You can view the full [code](https://github.com/SageJustus/question/tree/dev/demo1) here (maybe you need to disable the maven mirror repository)

Comment: `implementationClass = "SpringbootConventionPlugin"` does not include the package of the plugin. Change it to `implementationClass = "com.sage.server.SpringbootConventionPlugin"`

Comment: @aSemy That's working. But I used `api()` instead of `implementation()`, and the dependencies were not passed. Details are in the re-edited question.

Comment: Good to see that you fixed the problem with your plugin. Feel free to take my comment and write it up as a more complete answer. It looks like you have a new problem though, and so you should open a new question. At a first glance, I think this answer is relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/74607687/4161471

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @aSemy, My springboot project has been able to run successfully.

I solved the `dependencies were not passed` problem by renaming the subproject.

```
rootProject.name = "server"
include("core:api")
project(":core:api").name = "core-api"
include("feature:article:api")
project(":feature:article:api").name = "article-api"
```

this is not best practice. You can optimize the name of this subproject.

You can view the full [code](https://github.com/SageJustus/question/tree/dev/demo1) here(maybe you need to disable the maven mirror repository).